# How to use two gateways with the same IP address?

Tags: networking, route

I have to configure a NAT and manually split internet traffic between two gateways which are connected to a Linux box.

There was no problem if each gateway has a specific IP address. I can do this by `iproute2`:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
ip route add 2.3.4.5 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
ip route add 8.9.4.5 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

But my problem is so simple! I have no access to change the gateways addresses, and network ids. I just need to use two internet gateways with the same address from a Linux box, with kernel 3.2.0 and above.

```
                                                        +-----------+
                                                        | Gateway A |
                          +-----------------------+     |192.168.0.1|
                          |                   eth0+---->+-----------+
           +--------------+eth2   Linux Box       |
           |              |                   eth1+---->+-----------+
           |              +-----------------------+     | Gateway A |
           |                                            |192.168.0.1|
           |                                            +-----------+
  +--------+-----------+
  |  Private Network   |--------> Workstation A
  |                    |
  |    10.0.0.0/24     |--------> Workstation B
  +--------------------+
```

How can I solve this problem using Linux's amazing network tools (`mangling`, `snat` or something else)?

Comment: Hmm... could it be possible to use some kind of dirty `arp` hack to locally assign one of those gateways a different IP? - On second thought, all IP packets would have the locally assigned destination IP in their headers, and the gateway would probably discard those packages. Maybe some kind of iptables could fix those packets just before they leave the interface?

Comment: interesting trick, may be used alongside snat, to rewrite the outging packet's source address.can you provide me an example as answer?

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/389306/whats-the-best-way-to-accomodate-multiple-devices-that-all-want-to-use-the-same

Comment: sorry, no. I'm just wildly guessing here, I've never attempted something like this before.

Comment: Possibly related: a similar problem where the `iptables` `MARK` target is used to force packets to leave the machine on a specific interface.

Comment: `iptables` is the way to go... http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/stronger-firewall-examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got it. after some tries, i found the linux kernel does not have any problem in this situation. it works like charming ! by this iproute2 rules & routes:

*eth0: 192.168.0.231/24 --> Gateway A: dwl2100ap*

*eth1: 192.168.0.230/24 --> Gateway B: dwlg132*

Configuring interfaces:

```
ip addr add 192.168.0.231/24 dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.0.230/24 dev eth1
```

Adding two routing tables:

```
echo "1       dwl2100ap" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "2       dwlg132" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Adding routes to tables:

```
ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.231 table dwl2100ap
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table dwl2100ap

ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.0.230 table dwlg132
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 table dwlg132
```

Next, you set up the routing rules. These actually choose what routing table to route with. You want to make sure that you route out a given interface if you already have the corresponding source address:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.0.231 table dwl2100ap
ip rule add from 192.168.0.230 table dwlg132
```

Masquerading all outgoing packets:

```
iptables -tnat -APOSTROUTING -s10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

To let kernel to split bandwidth i can issue this route:

```
ip route add default scope global nexthop via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 weight 2 nexthop via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1 weight 1
```

To route manually:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
ip route add 8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
ip route add 8.8.4.4 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1
```

**EDIT 1:**

Additionally i can mark some packets by iptables:

```
iptables -tmangle -APREROUTING -i eth2 -s 10.0.0.4 -jMARK --set-mark 4
```

Then route them via routing policy:

```
ip rule add fwmark 4 table dwl2100ap
```

I wondering it works with two gateways with the same ip address. in kernel 3.2.0-53.

Comment: I was absolutely certain that Linux is able to do this, I just didn't know how :). Nicely done!

Comment: @Martin, Thanks for your friendly advice.Arp hack is a good idea, but no needed here.so the box can resolve each mac-address via separated ethernet. it's good if there was only one ethernet and two node with the same address.